# Does there exist a categorical approach to logarithms?

Tags: category-theory, logarithms

The title says it all; I have researched for literature on this, but to no avail. Has anyone come across any sort of categorical approach to logarithms?

Comment: What kind of a thing do you have in mind? What would you want it for?

Comment: was there a particular "categorical approach" to the exponential function that inspired this question?